# How to remove line if it contains a pattern only once in all file for a specific column

Tags: text-processing

My file contains several columns and the first one corresponds to id.
I want to remove a line if the id appears only once (in the first column) in the whole file.
If the id is present more than once I want to keep the line in file.
The id is composed of letters (and sometimes numbers), beginning with an A (all the other letters /numbers are in a random order). For example : `A2SGWS7CUGU8GB`

If I have :

```
# id             #column 2 ...
A2SGWS7CUGU8GB
A2SGWS7CUGU8GB
ADE8GST9URWPOS
ABXLMWJCQFGVXV
A2SGWS7CUGU8GB
```

I would like to remove the lines containing `ADE8GST9URWPOS` and `ABXLMWJCQFGVXV` because they only appear once. How could I do this?

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please edit your post to include more information about the file format: Is it tab- or space-separated? Is the ID always "one word"? Is there a "header" line that should be ignored? Other comment lines? Also please show what you already tried, and where you ran into trouble, so that contributors don't suggest solution you already know won't work.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, this would return all IDs that are duplicated and that you'd like to keep:

```
$ awk '{ print $1 }' <file | sort | uniq -d
A2SGWS7CUGU8GB
```

It does that by extracting the first whitespace-delimited field, the ID, using `awk`. This is then sorted and `uniq -d` is used to only output the IDs that are duplicated.

We can then use these (singular, in this case) IDs to extract the corresponding lines from the original file, which must first be sorted, using `join`:

```
$ join <( awk '{ print $1 }' <file | sort | uniq -d ) <( sort file )
A2SGWS7CUGU8GB
A2SGWS7CUGU8GB
A2SGWS7CUGU8GB
```

If your shell does not support process substitutions using `<(...)`, you can do this in a two-step fashion, using a temporary file:

```
$ sort -o file.sorted file
$ awk '{ print $1 }' <file | sort | uniq -d | join - file.sorted
A2SGWS7CUGU8GB
A2SGWS7CUGU8GB
A2SGWS7CUGU8GB
```

Using *only* `awk`, this could be done in the following way:

```
$ awk 'NR == FNR { count[$1]++; next } count[$1] > 1' file file
A2SGWS7CUGU8GB
A2SGWS7CUGU8GB
A2SGWS7CUGU8GB
```

Note that the file is mentioned twice on the command line, since it's read twice by the `awk` code.

The first time, the associative array `count` is populated by the number of times each ID is seen, and the second time each line that has an ID that was seen more than once is outputted.

The difference between the two approaches above is that the `awk` command presented last will preserve the ordering of the original data, but will consume memory proportional to the number of unique IDs. The first approach will generate sorted results and may be more apropriate for *very large* data.

---

For preserveing the header line, the commands need to be slightly modified:

```
$ join <( awk '{ print $1 }' <file | sort | uniq -d ) <( sort file ) | cat <(head -1 file) -
```

or

```
$ sort -o file.sorted file
$ awk '{ print $1 }' <file | sort | uniq -d | join - file.sorted > file.noheader
$ head -1 file | cat - file.noheader
```

or

```
$ awk 'NR == 1 ; NR == FNR { count[$1]++; next } count[$1] > 1' file file
```

Comment: To be absolutely guarded against "stray" comment and empty lines, you could use `awk 'FNR==NR{if (NF && ($1 !~ /^#/)) count[$1]++; next} !NF || /^#/ || count[$1]>1' file file`

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '
  !B {a[$1]++}
  B && a[$1] > 1
' B=0 file B=1 file
```

---

Get the first field(=ID) and sort it and thence uniquify the IDs and keep only the duplicated ones. Pass them to xargs and fashion an egrep ERE regex out of each such ID.

```
< file \
  cut -d" " -f1          \
| sort  | uniq -d        \
| xargs -I{} echo ^{}\\s \
| grep -Ef - file        \
;
```

---

Using `perl` we slurp the file `-0777` option and run a regex through the record and if at every line beginning `^`, we are able to see the first field(=ID) further down or the ID has already been encountered before, print the current line

```
perl -0777ne '
  () = m/(?msx)
      ^
      (?<line>
        (?<ID> A\w+)
        \h.*?\n
      )

      (?=
        (?:.*?\n)?
        (?<lukahead> \g{ID}|$)
      )

      (?{ my %seen;
        my($id_visible_ahead, $id_already_seen) =
          map { $_ > 0 } 
length($+{lukahead}), $seen{$+{ID}};

        print($+{line}),$seen{$+{ID}}++
          if $id_visible_ahead || $id_already_seen;
      })
   /g;
' file
```

**Output:**

```
A2SGWS7CUGU8GB
A2SGWS7CUGU8GB
A2SGWS7CUGU8GB
```